# How to get functions to be sychronous, in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am building a backend with nodeJS. 
Since the database call is asynchronous and I want to return its results I have to await the querys result. But then I would have to use await again making the function asynchronous. Is it possible to break this somehow and have synchronous functions?

My goal would be to have something like this.

```
function persistenceFunction(params){
   // Do something to await without this persistenceFunction having to be async
   return await pool.query('SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE a=?;',params);
}

function serviceFunction(params){
   validate(params);
   // do stuff
   return persistenceFunction(params);
}
```

For the database connection I am using the node db module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerations:
The following function will not work because in order for you to be able to use `await` you have to declare your function as `async`

```js
function persistenceFunction (params){
   // Do something to await without this persistenceFunction having to be async
   return await pool.query('SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE a=?;',params);
}
```

But since you are returning `pool.query` you don't actually need the await there, so a better alternative would be this.

```js
function persistenceFunction (params){
   // Do something to await without this persistenceFunction having to be async
   return pool.query('SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE a=?;',params);
}
```

Just remember that whatever part of your code that is calling `serviceFunction` will receive a `Promise` as a result, so it will have to be called in one of the following ways:

```js
function async something () {
   const params = {...}
   const res = await serviceFunction(params)
   // do something with res
}
```

OR

```js
function something () {
   const params = {...}
   serviceFunction(params).then((res) => {
      // do something with res
   })
}
```